# SQL pivot get products by orderNr

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have 2 tables:

- 'OrderHeader' with columns OrderNr and OrderContact.
- 'OrderDetail with columns OrderNr and OrderSerial.

For each ordernr there are max 3 orderserials.
So, what I'm trying to get is a table with columns:

- OrderNr
- OderContact
- OrderSerial1
- OrderSerial2
- OrderSerial3

I'm now stuck with my pivot

```
    SELECT  OrderNr,
        OderContact,
        [1] as OrderSerial1,
        [2] as OrderSerial2,
        [3] as OrderSerial3
FROM
    (select H.OrderNR as OrderNr,
            OrderContact as OderContact,
            OrderSerialsNr
    from OrderHeader H inner join OrderDetail D on H.OrderNr = D.OrderNr
    ) AS PivSource
PIVOT
(count(OrderSerialsNr) for OrderSerialsNr in([1],[2],[3])) as pvt
```

I used the adventureworks DB for this.

```
   USE [AdventureWorks2008R2]
GO

create view [test].[OrderHeader] (OrderNr,OrderContact)
as
SELECT  SalesOrderID,
        FirstName + ' ' + LastName

FROM         Sales.SalesOrderHeader INNER JOIN
                      Sales.Customer ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID = Sales.Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                      Person.Person ON Sales.Customer.PersonID = Person.Person.BusinessEntityID
GO

CREATE view [test].[OrderDetail] (OrderNr,OrderSerialsNr,Price)
as
SELECT [SalesOrderID]
      ,[ProductID]
      ,[unitPrice]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
  where SalesOrderID in (select SalesOrderID
                        from [AdventureWorks2008R2].[Sales].[SalesOrderDetail]
                        group by SalesOrderID
                        having COUNT(SalesOrderID) < 4)
GO
```

Please help cause I don't know where to look anymore :).

Comment: Please post some sample data from the two tables and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

To get data in pivot table the in claus should have correct data from table

you can get more idea from this query

if 1 and 2 are not in your table it will not appear as count and at a column value

```
CREATE TABLE #OrderHeader
(ORDERNR INT,
ORDERCONTACT CHAR(5))

CREATE TABLE #ORDERDETAIL
(ORDERNR INT,
ORDERSERIAL VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #OrderHeader VALUES ( 1, 'X')
INSERT INTO #ORDERDETAIL VALUES ( 1, 'X1')
INSERT INTO #ORDERDETAIL VALUES ( 1, 'X2')
INSERT INTO #ORDERDETAIL VALUES ( 1, 1)
INSERT INTO #ORDERDETAIL VALUES ( 1, 2)


SELECT * FROM #OrderHeader
SELECT * FROM #ORDERDETAIL

SELECT  OrderNr,
        OderContact,
        [1] as OrderSerial1,
        [2] as OrderSerial2,
        [3] as OrderSerial3
FROM
    (select H.OrderNR as OrderNr,
            OrderContact as OderContact,
            ORDERSERIAL
    from #OrderHeader H inner join #ORDERDETAIL D on H.OrderNr = D.OrderNr
    ) AS PivSource
PIVOT
(count(ORDERSERIAL) for ORDERSERIAL in([1],[2],[3])) as pvt


DROP TABLE #OrderHeader
DROP TABLE #ORDERDETAIL
```

Comment: Okay, so this is not possible with pivot, unless you know the values.

Thanks for the advice! I'll see for another way to do this.